# Extracting a substring using Matcher: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Tags: regex, scala, functional-programming

I am trying to use regex to extract a substring from a given string. I am doing this in Scala:

```
val pattern = Pattern.compile("(Word)+")
val matcher = pattern.matcher("WordWordRestOfString")
matcher.group(1)
```

The desired output is "WordWord", however, I keep getting an IllegalStateException.
I haven't really worked with Regex before, and cannot fully grasp how the matcher.group method works, but I have seen answers to questions suggesting the use of matcher.group(1).

Comment: Repeating the capture group will give you the value of the last iteration, which will be a single `Word`. You could repeat it as a non capturing group and get the matches instead See for example https://ideone.com/fD8t3b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the repeated capturing group only keeps the last captured value in the group memory buffer, so it is not surprising you onyl get `Word` as Group 1 value. See the [*Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

Second, you do not actually call the matcher `.find` or `.matches` method that actually trigger the regex search.

Third, you do not need to get Group 1 value here, you just need to get a full match:

```scala
val s = "WordWordRestOfStringWordWordWord"
val pattern = "(Word)+".r
// Single result:
val result = pattern.findFirstMatchIn(s).get
println(result) // => WordWord
// Multiple results:
val multiple_results = pattern.findAllMatchIn(s)
println(multiple_results.mkString(", ")) // => WordWord, WordWordWord
```

See the [Scala demo](https://rextester.com/BJWXNF34464)

Comment: Thank you! That actually solves my issue. Another approach that works was suggested in the comments by The fourth bird. Great to see it's not that complicated, I wish there were more detailed examples online

Answer (score 0):

If I use `group()` instead of `group(1)`, I do not face any issue getting the desired output in Java. I do not know Scala but I believe a Java code should work the same way is in Scala.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var pattern = Pattern.compile("(Word)+");
        var matcher = pattern.matcher("WordWordRestOfString");
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
WordWord
```

You can check [this excellent tutorial on Regex, by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html).